# Show an JavaScript alert from code

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a simple code such as following:

```
public void showQuery()
{
    try
    {
        //try something
        If(Success)
        {
            //Show JavaScript success message
        }
        else
        {
            //Show JavaScript missing something
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Show JavaScript code of error
    }
}
```

How can I show a this JavaScript from code?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: We can use javascript in VF page not in apex controller

Comment: and there is a reason you don't want to use `apex:pageMessages` ?

Comment: Rodolfo, where are you trying to do this ? What are you trying to do ? Why Javascript ?  Please understand that providing some more context and explaining the salesforce aspects of your question help us help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to render the error back to the page somehow. Here's one possible example:

```
<!-- page -->
<apex:outputText rendered="{!showMessage}" id="messageAlert">
<script>alert("{!JSENCODE(message)}")</script>
</apex:outputText>
```

Then, in your code:

```
public Boolean showMessage { get; set; }
public String message { get; set; }
public void showQuery() {
    showMessage = false;
    try {
        // Do stuff here
    } catch(Exception e) {
        showMessage = true;
        message = e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

The final part, then, is that you have to remember to render that script section:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!showQuery}" value="Query" reRender="messageAlert" />
```

Edit: Sometimes, variables "get lost", so you need to reRender the entire form to get the correct effect. Here's a fully functional example in my developer org.

```
public class showAlertController {
    public Boolean showMessage { get; set; }
    public String message { get; set; }
    public void showAlert() {
        showMessage = true;
        message = 'Hello World';
    }
}

<apex:page controller="showAlertController">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:outputText id="showAlertText" rendered="{!showMessage}">
            <script>
            alert('{!JSENCODE(message)}');
            </script>
        </apex:outputText>
        <apex:commandButton value="Show Alert" action="{!showAlert}" reRender="form" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I have an error!! It seems the syntax is incorrect. It changes me all the code to red and apex does not work.

Comment: @RodolfoLanshore The code I provided was only a fragment. Make sure that the variables are *outside* the function's body.

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is that the apex does not recognize <script> statement

Comment: @RodolfoLanshore Let me write up a fully functional example in my developer box, and I'll get back to you soon as I can.

Comment: @sfdcfox, why do we have to rerender the whole form instead of just wrapping the outputtext in a outputpanel and rerendering it?

Comment: @javanoob It has to do with how View State is transmitted when dealing with re-rendering. In order to optimize the experience when re-rendering, only some of the view state is sent instead of everything. Sometimes you can get away with binding hidden input elements, sometimes they get optimized away. In this case, I wasn't able to get the code to work correctly without re-rendering the entire form. This won't *always* be true, but it can be hard to predict exactly when it is necessary.

Comment: Thanks a a lot for these feedback!! linearly the JavaScript code does not work, the compiler does not understand that syntax.